# after cache clear, all datas cleared even add datas

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

https://github.com/moderna/cordova-plugin-cache

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady);
function onDeviceReady()
{
        var success = function(status) {
            //alert('Message: ' + status);
        }
        var error = function(status) {
        }
        window.cache.clear( success, error );
        window.cache.cleartemp(); //  
}
```

I'm using this plugin in my cordova project app page
and I found out that
after using above function and finished app forcely
then all window.localStorage data is cleared
although add some datas into localStorage after clear cache in android .
(like at success function)

I set the intro page with localStorageData
so sometimes it causes problems.

Is it a bug??
How I can add datas into localStorage after cacahe clear?

Comment: for safer way :  window.localStorage.setItem("password", "");

Comment: The reason that I'm using cache clear plugin is that picture upload problem. The picture doesn't changed quickly.